# Shoulder feels sore/strained after 10 sets of 10 on Bench Press?

Tags: gym, shoulders, muscle-soreness, upper-body-workout, bench-press

So I went to the gym today, I got on the bench and did 10 sets of 10 reps, using medium weight, took about 30 minutes to complete, only thing I did other than biking and a few chin ups, and now my shoulder feels a little sore? Does anyone know why?

Comment: 10 sets of 10 reps, maybe?

Comment: Uh... Yeah... And?

Comment: Ever think that 100 reps might do it?

Comment: 10 sets? If it's not muscle pain, it's probably inflammation. Aim for 2-4reps using a heavy weight. You don't build muscles with medium weight, you'll only maintain muscle. When you work it harder than its capacity, then it needs to actually get stronger

Comment: I do 1/4 of that volume and bench 250 at 185lbs. No idea what kind of training program would advise volume like that.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what's your regular routine like? Do your lower half and your back receive as much attention as your triceps and chest?

Comment: @Kneel Before Zod, I at least work my back and biceps as much as chest and triceps, and I also squat 3 times per week

Comment: @RobSterach That's good..... ***strangers don't let friends skip leg day*** :)

Answer (score 5):

**It's likely all the bench-pressing that you're doing.**

- Too much volume: 10x10 is a very high-volume program. Most lifters
  stick to around 3x10 or 4x8 for hypertrophy.
- It also might be a muscle imbalance. Your pectorals are stronger than
  your back-muscles, and it's screwing with the (very complicated)
  structures in your shoulders. Take a break from benching for a few
  weeks and do some more rows/pulldowns/chin-ups/face-pulls.